# Can you hyphenate paste tense verb for typesetting purposes?

Tags: hyphenation

One way to deal with line breaks is to have ragged justification (like in MS Word). Another is to vary interword spacing and use hyphens where necessary. I much prefer the latter. I am not 100% certain of the rules for this, however, and this isn't the sort of thing they teach anymore so I haven't been able to find an answer to my question.

That would be "Can I hyphenate words like 'stopped' as 'stop-ped' or perhaps 'stopp-ed' when they come at the end of a line?"

Comment: This is a style question; in other words, there's no single answer. Is there a particular style guide you have in mind?

Comment: Not exactly. I guess I go by the golden rule of "be consistent" while generally deferring to the Chicago style. I suppose a better question might be "is it wrong to do that?" rather than asking if its right.

Comment: Generally speaking, splitting "rules" (its not usually considered "hyphenation") lobby against breaking the word with fewer than 3 characters on either side.  And, of course, you're supposed to divide between syllables.  "Stopped" is one syllable.

Comment: Ah! That greatly improved my search results. I am getting some mixed messages though. One guide used "play-ed" as an example of how TO do it, but its a single syllable.

Comment: There is no single rule. As with most questions of style, it's subjective.